# for loop do not print complete filenames of files having spaces

Tags: windows, command-line

This is my for loop that i iterate over a folder

```
for /f %A in ('dir /b "G:\Files Sample\Samples\zip\txt"') do echo "%A"
```

My problem is the echo statement does not echo the complete name of the file when the filename contains spaces in it.

How do i correct this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /b "G:\Files Sample\Samples\zip\txt"') do @echo %A
```

You just needed to set `delims` to nothing so that it didn't split the input into columns on spaces.